# Can't install material-ui/core for react-native 17.0.1

Tags: react-native, npm, material-ui

Would anyone be able to clarify as to why this is not installing as it should?

$ npm install @material-ui/core

Here are the logs:

```
...

29 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/react 125ms (from cache)
30 timing idealTree Completed in 2086ms
31 timing command:install Completed in 2090ms
32 verbose stack Error: unable to resolve dependency tree
32 verbose stack     at Arborist.[failPeerConflict] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1011:25)
32 verbose stack     at Arborist.[loadPeerSet] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:991:36)
36 verbose node v15.0.0
37 verbose npm  v7.0.2
38 error code ERESOLVE
39 error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
40 error
41 error While resolving: [1mamazon-clone[22m@[1m0.1.0[22m
41 error Found: [1mreact[22m@[1m17.0.1[22m[2m[22m
41 error [2mnode_modules/react[22m
41 error   [1mreact[22m@"[1m^17.0.1[22m" from the root project
41 error
41 error Could not resolve dependency:
41 error [35mpeer[39m [1mreact[22m@"[1m^16.8.0[22m" from [1m@material-ui/core[22m@[1m4.11.0[22m[2m[22m
41 error [2mnode_modules/@material-ui/core[22m
41 error   [1m@material-ui/core[22m@"[1m*[22m" from the root project
41 error
41 error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
41 error this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
41 error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I got chuncks of the logs above that may tell what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this post has your solution:

https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2000.  It looks like a recent issue with an eslint dependency